# Hazelcast joining second instance failed on load all keys

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast

I'm using 3.6.1 version (Java 8). 
Running 2 instances on localhost (tcp config). 
When first instance up and running some data I'm starting the second instance. It joins the cluster , but immediately failed on  "load all keys" -

```
31, 2016 6:11:33 PM com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore
INFO: [localhost]:5701 [CoreCluster] [3.6.1] Starting to load all keys for map sentAlerts on partitionId=64

31, 2016 6:11:33 PM com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.LoadStatusOperation
SEVERE: [localhost]:5701 [CoreCluster] [3.6.1] Transition not allowed from     state NOT_LOADED to LOADED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transition not allowed from state NOT_LOADED to LOADED
at com.hazelcast.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:313)
at com.hazelcast.util.StateMachine.next(StateMachine.java:60)
at com.hazelcast.util.StateMachine.nextOrStay(StateMachine.java:70)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoader.trackLoading(MapKeyLoader.java:228)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.updateLoadStatus(DefaultRecordStore.java:115)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.LoadStatusOperation.run(LoadStatusOperation.java:48)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:172)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processOperation(OperationThread.java:198)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:132)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:124)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:99)
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Edit: Configuration snippet

```
    private static HazelcastInstance buildHazelcastInstance() {
    Config config = new Config().setGroupConfig(
            new GroupConfig().setName("cluster"));
    config.setNetworkConfig(new NetworkConfig().setJoin(new JoinConfig().setMulticastConfig(new MulticastConfig().setEnabled(false))
        .setTcpIpConfig(new TcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).setMembers(Arrays.asList("localhost")))));
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Edit2: The instance also have MongoMapStore, which is implementation of MapStore. When I'm not setting MapStoreConfig, the instances are working fine (second joining and able to read data of the first one), but if I reenabling MapStoreConfig the exception raised again ...

Comment: could you share config and map loader snippet?

Comment: @VikGamov I added config. Thanks.

Comment: Is the second instance joining when the first one is loading the keys or has the load finished when you start the second one?

Comment: @tom.bujok In the beginning Mongo is empty, and the first node is storing constantly data inside, and meanwhile the second node tries to join the cluster

Comment: You probably use lazy loading, as it is the default value. I got around this problem by using InitialLoadMode.EAGER for the MapStoreConfig. This loads the data up to the maxSize first. But it blocks every interaction until it's finished loading. Not sure if that is okay for you.